# Baahsto destroyed mid action

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

When using the The Enclave of Endlings environment deck how do you handle it when the Baahsto card is in play and is destroyed while it is being resolved. For example while a hero is resolving the effects of the card that was put in play it causes Baahsto to be destroyed due to chain AE damage happening. When this happens does the card still fully resolve and all hero's put the top card into play? Or does it stop at the point where it was destroyed? They way my group looks at the rule is the card needs to fully resolve and all hero's play the top card of the deck even if it was destroyed while it is happening.

> Baahsto (7 HP)
>
> "At the end of the environment turn, put the top card of the villain deck into play.
> Then, put the top card of each hero deck into play in turn order. If a limted card already in play would be put into play, discard that card instead."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to assume that the core rules are not changed in some way by this expansion as I cannot find the rulebook online. The [core rulebook](http://sentinelsofthemultiverse.com/system/files/downloads/Sentinels%20of%20the%20Multiverse%20Enhanced%20Edition%20Rulebook.pdf) has this to say on conflict resolution:

> Over the course of a game, there are situations in which multiple effects would occur simultaneously or have competing effects. In all situations, card effects that happen simultaneously occur in the order in which the card entered play.

<s>Since Baahsto entered play first you should play each hero's top card first from his effect. Once that has resolved you should go through the effects (if any) of the hero cards in the order they were played (turn order).</s>

**EDIT:**
In short: I was wrong, there is now an [errata](http://www.spiffworld.com/sotm/files/sotm_rules_and_clarifications.pdf).

Relevant passage:

> **Destroying a card before it’s finished**
>
> When a card is destroyed before it can finish its effect, any remaining effect is cancelled.
>
> For example, Ra has his “Flame Barrier” out, and a villain target deals
>   all hero targets damage. The players decide to target Ra first, and Ra
>   immediately retaliates, dealing enough damage to destroy the
>   attacker. With the attacking target gone, there is nothing to continue
>   dealing damage to the rest of the hero targets.

So destroying Baahsto stops the remaining hero(es) from drawing a card from their deck.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, when I am playing using the offical ios app (and I think for computer and android as well) if I use an ae damage ability such as tempest and I damage something that returns damage then the ae ability is paused while the return damage happens. After the return damage is done the ae damage finishes up and is paused by any other effects triggered by it.

Comment: I've not used the app but that seems to contradict the rules in the original rulebook. Any printed rules that show this to be the case?

Comment: The app is made by the same people who make the physical game so I would assume it is following the rules correctly.

Comment: Can you test what Baahsto does in the App?

Comment: It is not currently in the app.  Currently it contains the base game, unity, ambescade, and the Mars environment.  I am not sure when that set will enter the app.

Comment: I'm currently unsure how to refactor my answer to this question. Personally I feel destroying Baahsto as the app seems to suggest would make the most sense in game (in general it is already stacked against players, I feel, and this improves tactical play). That being said that seems to completely go against the rules as written in the rulebook. Unless you can think of a technical way/errata that solves this?

Comment: If you can't test Baahsto directly you could substitute a similar test with Fanatic's Power.  If you can set up a way to get killed between the first and second damage types being done, that should be the same from a rules and timing perspective.

Comment: See edited answer above.